# How can I create a private task list in JIRA?

Tags: jira, issue-tracking, tasklist

Our company is new to JIRA.

We are trying to work out if our users can create a private task list in JIRA?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you could define an issue security scheme, which would make the reporter the only one with access to the issues.

So in your place I would try:

- setting up a separate project, let's say OWN ISSUES
- creating and assigning a new issue security scheme with only security level
- assigning the issue reporter to the only security level

Haven't tried it though.